# Checking the presence of multiple words in a variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code the presence of a single word in a sentence and it's working fine.

```
var str ="My best food is beans and plantain. Yam is also good but I prefer yam porrage"

if(str.match(/(^|\W)food($|\W)/)) {

        alert('Word Match');
//alert(' The matched word is' +matched_word);
}else {

        alert('Word not found');
}
```

Here is my issue: I need to check presence of multiple words in a sentence (eg: **food,beans,plantains** etc) and then also alert the matched word.
something like `//alert(' The matched word is' +matched_word);`

I guess I have to passed the searched words in an array as per below:

```
var  words_checked = ["food", "beans", "plantain"];
```

Comment: _"I guess I have to passed the searched words in an array "_ - yes, that will work. Put all the works in an array and then iterate over the array and use `str.includes(currentWord)` to check the existence of current word in the string.

Comment: `\b(food|beans|plantain|yam)\b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string contains any of array of strings without regExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925420/check-if-string-contains-any-of-array-of-strings-without-regexp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to solve this. Simply loop through the list of words to check, build the regex as you go and check to see if there is a match. You can read up on how to build Regexp objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
var str ="My best food is beans and plantain. Yam is also good but I prefer 
          yam porrage"
var words = [
    "food",
    "beans",
    "plantain",
    "potato"
]

for (let word of words) {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(^|\\W)${word}($|\\W)`)

    if (str.match(regex)) {
        console.log(`The matched word is ${word}`);
    } else {
        console.log('Word not found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regular expression by joining the array of words by `|`, then surround it with word boundaries `\b`:

```js
var words_checked = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`\b(?:${words_checked.join('|')})\b`);
var str = 'fooNotAStandaloneWord baz something';

console.log('Match:', str.match(pattern)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "I am happy, We all are happy";
var count = countOccurences(text, "happy");
```

// count will return 2
//I am passing the whole line and also the word for which i want to find the number of occurences
// The code splits the string and find the length of the word

```
function countOccurences(string, word){
      string.split(word).length - 1;
}
```

Comment: Would you edit your answer to explain how it answers the question? Future readers may find that useful.